# Menú activo en sidebar en PHP

Tags: php, sidebar

Estoy trabajando con PHP, en mi sistema tengo un Sidebar que funciona sin problemas. Pero lo que le falta y estoy intentando realizar, es que cuando este posicionado en una pagina, en el sidebar este destacada la posición actual.

En mi pagina menu.php creo el sidebar con sus opciones:

```
 <ul>
   <li>
     <a href="admin.php">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
       <span>Inicio</span>
     </a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href="pasantia.php">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>
       <span>Mis Solicitudes</span>
     </a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Posteriormente en la pagina header.php agrego el sidebar

```
<div class="sidebar">
   <?php include_once('menu.php');?>
</div>
```

Y en el resto de las paginas llamo al header.php

```
<?php include_once('layouts/header.php'); ?>
```

Lo que he intentado hacer pero no me ha resultado es agregar el siguiente código en menu.php

```
 <li <?php if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']=="/admin.php") { ?>  class="active_nav" <?php } ?>>
   <a href="admin.php">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
    <span>Inicio</span>
   </a>
 </li>
```

En mi código css cree el estilo:

```
 .active_nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 65px 0 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  background: #d80e0e;
  border-right: 1px solid #014185;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

Espero que alguien me pueda orientar o indicar que estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví, agregando la siguiente función:

```
function active($currect_page)
{
  $url_array = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  $url = end($url_array);
  if($currect_page == $url)
  {
   echo 'active';
  }
}
```

Defino el estilo CSS:

```
  <style type="text/css">
    .active {
    color: #ff6600 !important;
    background-color:#195cb6;
   }
  </style>
```

Y finalmente agrego el estilo al li

```
  <li>
    <a class="<?php active('admin.php');?>" href="admin.php">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
      <span>Inicio</span>
    </a>
  <li>
```